# Why is my emblem image loaded last on my website

Tags: html, css, browser, loading

On my site my emblem image is always loaded last. On my site there are other images too however everyone of them is loaded (displayed on screen) before my emblem image. How do I find out why? There is no JS code (of my creation) that would do that ...

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Where is the photo located in the layout of the code? Like Mik3NL requested, code is king.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with deferring images. This with, or without JQuery or Lady Loading ...

Is the image loaded in the HTML or in CSS (as background OR content object)?
When it's loaded with CSS, what I think, the CSS has been deferred / moved to the bottom of the page. Check the file where the CSS files are being loaded and look for things like: 'DEFER' or "ASYNC" ...

Good luck!

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer